# How to create depended parameters in SSRS report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I can create depended parameters with cascade parameters. 
when I create cascade parameter ı can just one direction choosing. but ı want to choose parameter Bidirectional choosing.

for example I have @region_name, @countr_name and @state parameter.
If ı use cascade parameters 
ı can show, if I choose region_name then ı can choose country_name then if ı choose country_name ı can choose state

but ı want to create a report. for example,
if ı choose country name ı must choose state or I want to choose firstly state then ı must to choose country name depends on state.
actually ı want to create depended parameter. 
could you help me please?

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure if you can do that with SSRS unless you do it in separate app and then feed parameters to SSRS report.

Comment: You cannot do this in vanilla SSRS, but you can work around it with procedures.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Actually I want to join two parameters. two parameters must be depended each other. could you give me an example how can ı do like this?

Comment: you can go through this link we may get idea for creating dependent Parameters   https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3466/cascaded-parameters-in-sql-server-reporting-services/

Answer (score 0):

IN SSRS, parameters cannot reference each other.  They are evaluated in the order the parameters are listed in the designer, from top to bottom.  If a higher parameter tries to reference a lower parameter, the designer will through an error and you will not be able to preview or deploy the report.

Possible work around:
Change one of the parameters to a string, accepting any text.  The second parameter would look for matches in the State or Country tables and return a multi-valued list of State/Country matches for that string.

For example, if I type in 'Mexico' as my search string, the 2nd parameter would display

```
'New Mexico, USA' 
'Baja California, Mexico'
'Campeche, Mexico'
```